# Replacement for require in Vuejs 3 with Vite for image array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm currently switching to vite with vuejs and have the following problem:

I have a component in debugging that displays images from a folder:

```
imageArray: [
     require ("../ assets / dummies / Mission -1.jpg"),
     require ("../ assets / dummies / Mission -2.jpg"),
     require ("../ assets / dummies / Mission -3.jpg"),
     require ("../ assets / dummies / Mission -4.jpg")
]
```

in the component is the following div

```
<div: class = "bgClass" v-if = "isDebug () == true"> </div>
```

there is then the following dynamic class with de rich simple that can scroll through the images.

```
computed: {
     bgClass: function () {
      
       return {
           backgroundImage: 'url (' + this.imageArray [this.imagePos] + ')',
           ...
       }
     }
   }
```

Required is not available in Vite, and I would not like to convert the old vue2 components to the vue3 composition API.

how can I simply load the images into an array and scroll through the component.

Comment: Tried `import()`instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create function:

[check vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url)

```
const useImage = ((url) => {
  return new URL(`/src/${url}`, import.meta.url).href;
});
```

and create global property (in main.js):

```
app.config.globalProperties.$image = useImage;
```

then use it like:

```
$image(imageUrl)
```

Comment: do you need to add a build target to es2020? still cant get this method to work.

Comment: This solution works, but not for Nuxt3. After the hydration step the Nuxt3 if SSR is enabled. In this case you have to query the image element and update the `src` attribute manually.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Vite and had the same problem. I read other people's advice and experimented. Here's an example using v-for, in case it helps others.

```html
<template>
    <div
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
    >
        <img
            :src="`${imageUrl}${item.image}.jpg`"
            :alt="item.description"
        >
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    setup() {
        const imageUrl = new URL("../assets/images/", import.meta.url).href;
        return { imageUrl };
    },
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Object,
            default: function() {
                return {};
            },
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried multiple versions of this, for dynamic imports, but the output is <img src=file:///D:/....>